# Как заполнить массив-строку одной командой?

Tags: массивы, c++

Как заполнить одномерный массив единовременно, то есть не по одному элементу (первое число - Enter - второе число - Enter - ...), а например (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 Enter), как обработать подобный ввод?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получил в ходе экспериментов:

```
int a[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
cin >> a[i];
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Оба случая одинаково

```
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
...
int array[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  if (scanf("%d", array + i) != 1)
    errx(EX_DATAERR, "Bad input");
```

Comment: avp, можно ли обойтись cin, cout?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Суть не меняется. 

Вы про потоки ввода-вывода почитайте что-нибудь и поэкспериментируйте немного.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[3];

    cin >> arr[0] >> arr[1] >> arr[2]; // обеспечивает ввод трех чисел разделенных пробелами и подтверждение клавишей enter

    cout << "a: " << arr[0] << " b: " << arr[1] << " c: " << arr[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: этот код отлично введет, даже если на вход подать так `5<enter><enter>10<enter><enter>5`. Задача куда интереснее, если нужно, чтобы enter был как раз "окончанием ввода.

Comment: @KoVadim такой подход также отлично ведет себя со смешанными данными. А я вообще пришел к выводу, что надо избавлять себя от сишных конструкций, чтоб код логичней ставал и проще к чтению.

Comment: @KoVadim а насчет вашего интереса то он скорей закончитца на этом http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Comment: я знаю о getline. Но тогда нужна ещё одна функция, типа "split". А ТС хочет "в одну строку".

Comment: ну можно прочитать getline'om как string и потом sstream'ом распарсить. не?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы прочитать неизвестное заранее количество разделённых пробелами целых чисел, можно использовать `vector` и `istream_iterator<int>`:

```
std::istream_iterator<int> numbers(std::cin), eof;
std::vector<int> a(numbers, eof);
```

Полный пример:

```
#include <algorithm> // copy
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers(std::cin), eof;
  std::vector<int> a(numbers, eof);
  std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

`std::copy()` используется, чтобы напечатать каждое число из вектора на новой строке.

Пример использования:

```
$ g++ read-vector.cc -o read-vector && echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 | ./read-vector
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```