# Работа функции std::basic_istream::get

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

У меня есть файл с последовательностью `int` чисел. Необходимо в цикле считывать по одному **числу**, чтобы проводить с ним манипуляции. В [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) сказано, что метод `in.get()` возвращает `int_type`. Что этот тип означает?

```
std::ifstream in("in.txt");
std::cout << in.get(); // печатает код первого символа файла, а надо первое число
```

Comment: Чтобы числа в вектор скопировать из текстового файла, [можно `istream_iterator<int>` использовать.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385618/23044)

Comment: @jfs да, но мне нужно ещё манипулировать ими по мере считывания

Comment: манипулируйте, ничто вам не мешает. Что вы думаете stl алгоритмы, которые принимают first, last InputIterator делают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что числа в Вашем файле хранятся в текстовом представлении и Вы неправильно их считываете. Фактически, Вы читаете текстовый файл посимвольно, получая числовой код прочитанных символов. Вместо этого нужно читать до первого пробельного символа и преобразовывать полученную строку в целое число. Для этого можно воспользоваться оператором чтения из потока.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    if (in.is_open()) {
        int i;
        while (in >> i) {
            std::cout << i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: так а что `int_type` означает?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/ Целочисленный тип, который может хранить код символа. Зависит от параметра `_CharT` шаблона `template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits> std::basic_ifstream` В случае `std::ifstream` `_charT == char` и `int_type == int`.

Comment: получается считать несимвольный тип можно только с помощью `>>` ?

Comment: @bob Можно считать, что да.

Comment: ясно, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @bob Ну почему? `string` читается с помощью `getline`, например. Можно связать итераторы с потоком и читать любой тип с помощью `copy`. Опять же, мы говорим о текстовом режиме или о бинарном? `read` позволяет читать что угодно :)

Comment: Проверку на открытие файла, имхо, тут можно безболезненно убрать.

Comment: @Harry `string` - набор символов, т.е. `getline` читает символы, итераторы используют внутри `>>`, про `read` не знаю, думаю то же самое

Comment: @bob Тогда - исходя из этой логики - `int`  это тоже просто четыре символа :) Нет вопросов...

Answer (score 1):

[`in.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) это аналог `getchar()` -- читает отдельные символы (char) из потока. Метод возвращает `int_type` вместо `char_type`, чтобы была также возможность вернуть индикатор конца файла (eof).

Чтобы числа в вектор скопировать из текстового файла, [можно istream_iterator использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385618/23044):

```
#include <algorithm> // copy
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers(std::cin), eof;
  // копируем по одному числу из ввода в вывод
  // std::copy(numbers, eof, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); 
  // или в вектор можно сохранить для дальнейшей обработки
  std::vector<int> a(numbers, eof);
  std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

`istream_iterator<int>(in)` использует аналог `in >> i` внутри. Подробнее: [Как найти слово?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/384839/23044)